Error with sumproduct along subtotal to handle filtered values
I am trying to lookup for certain words in my table and turn them into a value in another table then sum all the values. That part is working fine, but now I want to work it only with filtered values so I've tried to do that with the SUBTOTAL part of the formula. It won't work with or without filters and I'm not sure why. Tried the evaluation tool but it turns the subtotal into errors, then into values and when trying to multiply against the result of the other formula inside the sumproduct turns them again into errors.
I don't know if this is because they are trying to multiply different size matrix or how to handle this.
This is the formula I'm trying:
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(M5:M500, {"KE", "BF", "LF", "SOP", "ME", "ME+", "PS"}) *
HLOOKUP("Analytics Data", SIZING!$D$1:$D$8, MATCH({"KE", "BF", "LF", "SOP", "ME", "ME+", "PS"}, SIZING!$A$1:$A$8, 0), FALSE) * SUBTOTAL(3, OFFSET(M5, ROW(M5:M500)-ROW(M5), 0)))

there is data only in a few rows, tried to resize the formula only to the rows with data but with no luck.
What am I missing or doing wrong?

What is =OFFSET(M5, ROW(M5:M500)-ROW(M5), 0) supposed to return?

Supposedly it returns all the rows between the range minus the first one (the header) and along with subtotal(3, ...) it  only returns the visible ones. @rachel

Then you need =OFFSET(M5, 1, 0, ROWS(M5:M500)-1)

Maybe you are right, will try that out @rachel. Though I've already found out the solution with  nkalvi's answer.

Wondering whether this is what you want:

lookup and store values in values
for each cell in M5:M500 get the sum by multiplying

0 if hidden SUBTOTAL(103, m)
match words
values



This requires Excel for Microsoft 365. Please let me know if you're on an older version.
=LET(
    words, {"KE", "BF", "LF", "SOP", "ME", "ME+", "PS"},
    values, HLOOKUP(
        "Analytics Data",
        SIZING!$A$1:$D$8,
        MATCH(words, SIZING!$A$1:$A$8, 0),
        FALSE
    ),
    SUM(MAP(M5:M500, LAMBDA(m, SUM(SUBTOTAL(103, m) * (m = words) * values))))
)


You're most welcome @Damian!
